# How to move Adobe Lightroom sliders via C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, lightroom

I would like to be able to move Adobe Lightroom's slider controls (Exposure, Contrast, etc) from my C# application. Using Spy++ I can get info about the slider controls (class msctls_trackbar32), but I lack a knowledge of how to control them from my application.

I hope someone can provide some code or ideas to start with.

Goal is to create a C# application that acts as a "driver" between Lightroom and a microcontroller driven dial controller, to control each of Lightroom's slider via physical rotary dial instead of mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Have you looked into whether Lightroom has any extension points you could hook into to accomplish this programmatically?  An API or any kind of scripting support, for example?  There might be a more reliable means of achieving your goal than trying to manipulate its UI from another process.

Comment: There is scripting (Lua) API for addons, but as far as I know there's no way to manipulate sliders.

Comment: But perhaps you can programmatically manipulate the same underlying values that the sliders control?  The sliders in the Lightroom UI might even detect the changes and update themselves to reflect your new values.  Worth looking into, I'd say, as the results could potentially be a best case outcome.

Comment: There already is some software to achieve this. _MIDI2LR_ on GitHub comes in mind, but there may be others.